# Testcontainers doesn't use local docker image

Tags: java, docker, testcontainers

I have slow internet connection, but I already have docker image that I need.
`docker image ls`:

```
yandex/clickhouse-server   20.1.8.41           3edfaacaf3ed        5 weeks ago         487MB
```

So, I am trying to use it in testcontainers with specified version (not *latest*)

```
@Rule
public ClickHouseContainer clickHouseContainer = (ClickHouseContainer)new ClickHouseContainer("yandex/clickhouse-server:20.1.8.41");

@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.println(clickHouseContainer.getJdbcUrl());
}
```

or with generic one:

```
public GenericContainer genericContainer = new GenericContainer("yandex/clickhouse-server:20.1.8.41");
```

But the result is error:

```
Caused by: com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Could not pull image: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

How can I tune testcontainers to use local images?

Answer (score 1):

By default, testcontainers [uses the local cache](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/advanced_options/#image-pull-policy), but it also relies on several public images [“to perform different actions like startup checks, VNC recording and others”](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/#customizing-images), including container cleanup with [Ryuk](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/#customizing-ryuk-resource-reaper).

I think the loading of some of these auxiliary images is what could be failing in your case. Try pulling them in manually. My bet is on `quay.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.2.3`, since you shouldn’t really need the rest.

Comment: I think this is likely to be the cause - you could try increasing the log level for `org.testcontainers` to `DEBUG` to see what image it's trying to pull. If it's the `ryuk` image, you could follow the instructions [here](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/#customizing-images) to configure Testcontainers to use an alternative, local, image.